# How can I return throws in java with false?

Tags: java

For example :

```
public abstract boolean isColumnFull(int col) throws IllegalColumnException {    
for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
     for (int j=0;j<7;j++) {
         if ((col>=0) && (col<=6)) 
            return true;
     else false;

}
```

How can I return false and use the throws for IllegalColumnException?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "use throws"?

Comment: never seen an abstract method with implementation before. that would definitely give a compilation error.

Comment: First, abstract methods don't have body. 
Second, briefly, you must create an `IllegalColumnException` class with extending `Exception` class. In `else` block in `isColumnFull` method, you must create and throw `IllegalColumnException` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and question isn't particularly clear, but I'm assuming you want to throw an exception where the column passed is out of range?

Your for loop iteration is pointless with the col check you've got, since neither i nor j are checked. So I assume this is actually part of your check to see if the column is full. I don't know how you mean to actually test this. However, ignoring this, you can validate and throw the exception up front, leaving you to return true out false once you determine is the column is full.

```
public boolean isColumnFull(int col) throws IllegalColumnException {    
    if (col < 0 || col > 6) {
        throw new IllegalColumnException();
    }
    // your test for checking a full column, returning true or false
}
```

This makes the assumption you've already created your exception class.

Answer (score -3):

```
public boolean isColumnFull(int col) {  
    try {           
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<7;j++) {
                if ((col>=0) && (col<=6))  {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: abstract method can not have a body.

Comment: What are you catching there (other than everything) and how does this answer the question about throwing and specialised exception? The question is unclear and code odd, but this answer actually just makes it worse.

Comment: @Jumwah I read it as he wanted to return false if he has an exception.